# C Generic Print Array function - printing String Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, generics, printing

I'm trying to write a generic printing arrays function in C and somehow it doesn't work well with a String array.
Here's the main:

```
#define LEN 20

typedef struct {
    char name[LEN]; // worker's name
    int salary; // worker's salary
    char **childArr; // array of children names
    int numChildren; // number of children
} Worker;

void printArray(void* arr, int size, int typeSize,  void (*print)(void*));
void printString(void* s);
void printWorker(void* worker);

void main() {
    // arrays of children's names
    char *chBamba[] = { "Bambale1", "Bamb2", "Bamb3", "Bambook4", "Bambookle5" };
    char *chBisli[] = { "Bislile1", "Bischick2", "Bislile3", "Bis4"};
    int nBamba = sizeof(chBamba) / sizeof(*chBamba);
    int nBisli = sizeof(chBisli) / sizeof(*chBisli);

    // array of workers
    Worker a[] = { {"Printf", 10, NULL, 0}, {"Bisli", 20, chBisli, nBisli},
{"TapooChips", 3, chBamba, nBamba}, {"Bamba", 19, chBamba, nBamba} };

    printArray(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(Worker), sizeof(Worker), printWorker);

}
```

And the functions:

```
void printArray(void* arr, int size, int typeSize,  void (*print)(void*)) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        print((char*)arr+i *typeSize);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void printString(void* s) {
    char* str = (char*)s;
    printf("[ %s ]", *str);
}

void printWorker(void* worker) {
    Worker* w = (Worker*)worker;
    printf("%s\t %d...(%d) ", w->name, w->salary, w->numChildren);
    if (w->numChildren != 0)
        printArray(w->childArr, w->numChildren, LEN, printString);

    printf("\n");
}
```

After printing the data of the second worker and going to the "children" array, the code breaks...

any idea why? and how can i fix it?

after editing this: `printArray(w->childArr,w->numChildren,sizeof(w->childArr[0]),printString);`

and this: `printf("[ %s ]",str);`

i now have the following print:
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcbCV.png)

Comment: Well, `printf("[ %s ]",*str);` certainly isn't good, and your compiler should have threw up a big fat warning telling you so. `str` is `char*`, so `*str` is `char`, and that doesn't bode well with `%s`. Basically, you lied to `printf` when you promised it a pointer to char and gave it char. And fyi, the cast in `char *str = (char*)s;` isn't needed; in C cast to or from like-const `void*` is automatic.

Comment: You don't use the right type `size_t` for indexing. And you cast for nothing `Worker* w = (Worker*)worker;` => `Worker* w = worker;`

Comment: @Stargateur - it doesn't matter for the compiler.

Comment: @WhozCraig -  Can you please look at the new edit i just did and tell me why i have this ugly prints?

Comment: @LjTiNo I don't know what for you doesn't matter for the compiler but use `size_t` matter.

Comment: It's alright.. @StoryTeller solved it. thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line here:

```
printArray(w->childArr,w->numChildren,LEN,printString);
```

You pass `LEN` as the size of the element in the array, which is probably way bigger than the size of an array element. This makes the loop in `printArray` go outside the array boundaries, where any access is undefined behavior.

Your array contains pointers to strings. You need to pass `sizeof(char*)`. Or, in a more [D.R.Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) manner:

```
printArray(w->childArr, w->numChildren, sizeof w->childArr[0], printString);
```

---

Your `printString` function does the wrong type conversion. You must remember that `printArray` passes a pointer to the current element into the callback. Since your iterate over an array of `char*`, it will pass a `char**`. With that in mind:

```
void printString(void *vpStr) {
    char **pStr = vpStr;
    printf("[ %s ]", *pstr);
}
```

Comment: Well.. it solved half the problem... now it prints.. but not what i asked it to print... can you look a the edit of my question?

Comment: @LjTiNo - See my edit. Type erasure requires minute attention to details.

Comment: i had to do it with char** str =(char**) s; (idk why my compiler won't let me without the casting..) but it works! you are awesome! :)

Comment: @LjTiNo - It doesn't let you because you are compiling with a C++ compiler. This is one of many instances where the languages differ. But I'm glad you have a working program now :)

Comment: Well.. im using visual studio 2010.. how can i use C compiler instead of C++?

Comment: @LjTiNo - Do your files have a `cxx` or `cpp` extension?

Comment: i use the cpp but change it to filename.c

Comment: @LjTiNo - That makes VS treat the source as C. But if it complains like you say, it means they don't implement the C standard completely. Keep the cast to appease a bad compiler :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, the method you are using is how this is traditionally done in C. But in modern C you can write such generic functions in a better way: type safe and without the need for function pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define print_array(data, n)         \
  _Generic((*data),                  \
           int: print_int,           \
           char: print_char)(data,n) \


void print_int (const int* data, size_t n)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", data[i]);
  }
}

void print_char (const char* data, size_t n)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    printf("%c ", data[i]);
  }
}



int main (void)
{
  int int_array [3] = {1, 2, 3};
  const char* char_array = "hello world";

  print_array(int_array, 3);
  printf("\n");
  print_array(char_array, strlen(char_array)); 
  printf("\n");

}
```